# Bootstrap - White border surrounding panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this website that I'm working on, it involves it's "main" content in a bootstrap panel. The ideal width for that panel is `670px`. So what I do is that I create a parent which is `width: 670px`. This is my output:

[image]

What annoys me so much is that big block of white at the right. How to solve that issue so that it'll dissapear?

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="  panel_big">
                <div class="panel_top_orange">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    <span>Welkom!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>

                            </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.panel_big {
        overflow: hidden !important; 
            border: 3.5px solid rgba(213, 220, 226, 0.9) !important;
            width:  670px;
    }
```

So how do I remove this whitespace? I already tried overriding the bootstrap settings by giving the panel a width of 670 pixels, but the space was still there...

Thanks.

Comment: Explain more clearly your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place everything inside this div

```
<div class="container">
...
<div>
```

If you are using bootstarp.

Comment: I just did, creates more whitespace... Now there's also some whitespace at the left of the container...

Comment: That's what it does. It places everything in the middle of container so that it doesn't look bad. If you don't want any spaces at all. Try to adjust width attribute. Try this `width : auto` or `overflow-x` property

Answer (score 0):

You need to center position of .panel_big by using `margin: auto` and better use width: 100% with max-width of 670px, when browser width will be smaller than 670px .panel_big will start to fit its width to browser width. Here's the code:

```
.panel_big {
  overflow: hidden !important; 
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(213, 220, 226, 0.9) !important;

  /* added code */
  width:  100%;
  max-width: 670px;
  margin: auto;
}
```